# Exporting MySQL Database into single SQL File in TOAD

Tags: mysql, toad

Using TOAD, is it possible to export an entire MySQL database to a single file?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in TOAD for MySQL. See the answer to the question below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240173/how-do-i-generate-a-script-of-all-database-objects-in-toad-for-mysql

Kind Regards, MB